# Flutter and Cloud Firestore fetch issue

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I have a problem with Flutter and Cloud Firestore from Firebase.
I already can add data to the database but I can't fetch it, because every time I call my method I get null back.

Here is my code:

```
dynamic getFromDatabase(String path, String item) {
  DocumentReference _docu = Firestore.instance.document('$path');
  var data;
  _docu.get().then((datasnapshot) {
    if(datasnapshot.exists){
      data = datasnapshot.data['$item'];
    }
  });
  return data;
}
```

This is where I call the method:

```
print((await getFromDatabase("User/$_uid","Vorname")));
```

And the error:

```
I/flutter (26289): null
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Firestore before. Only the normal database of firebase. But I think this is a async timing issue. It looks like it's returning null before it can complete the datasnapshot. (PS. datasnapshot is spelled wrong). Try something like this. Like I said. Not sure if it works.

```
Future<String> getFromDatabse(String path, String item){
  DocumentReference _docu = Firestore.instance.document(path);
  _docu.get().then((datasnapchot){
    if(datasnapchot.exists){
      return datasnapchot.data[item];
    }
  });
}
```

And when calling the method. Do this.

```
String getData = await getFromDatabse(path, item);
```

(PS also database is spelled wrong haha)

Comment: So i changed my code a little bit and I tried what you said but it's still not working.

Comment: Can you make a 1 file example that i can copy paste into my dev environment? and ill try to fix it for you in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

A good option is using the FutureBuilder widget.
You can use it inside a StatelessWidget, avoiding to implemente a StatefulWidget

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: Firestore.instance.document(path).get(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('Something went wrong.');
    }

    DocumentSnapshot docSnap = snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot;
    return Text(docSnap.data['doc_field']);
  }
)
```